# git push http-origin mybranchname problems

Tags: git, macos, zsh

Hi I have a remote repo that I before could push against with no problem and still can from another computer with the same git remotes.
my remotes is as following:

http-origin http://gitlab.xx.xx/xx.git (fetch)

http-origin http://gitlab.xx.xx/xx.git (push)

when i do my git push http-origin mybranchname i get following error:

remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.xx.xx/xx.git' not found

does anyone know why this is happening. I am running os x with terminal with zsh

Answer (score 0):

check that links for push/pull are correctly set on Your OS X - write in console from root folder of project `git remote -v`. Compare it with links shown on gitlab in your repo. If it is correct - try `git push --set-upstream origin nameOfBranchYouWantToPush`. If this does not work - the problem might be or with permissions, or, if you are using ssh - with rsa keys

Comment: the remotes are same on a computer that does not work and the one that work. Tried to re-add the remote also but same problem